# Parsing or extracting data for input in a database

Tags: regex, parsing, data-extraction

I have the following text file:

```
VERDICT: 
MR. FOREMAN:  Guilty.        
THE COURT:  Accused and, you have been found guilty on the charges as you have heard the Foreman for the jury say.  You are remanded.  I have requested a probation report and you are remanded until sentencing, until the Court receives the probation report. 
THE COURT:  Mr. Foreman and members of the jury, on behalf of the administration of justice   
THE CLERK:  Joh Doe the jury have found you guilty.  Have you anything to say before Her Ladyship, the Judge, proceeds to sentence you?                      
SENTENCE:
THE COURT:  John Doe.
```

I would like to use the keywords such as verdict, foreman, court, clerk, sentence as tags to enter this information in a database. Please tell me how I can extract these words to create tags to form an xml document to place it in a database. i have been searching using regex and data extraction but I have not found anything as yet.

Comment: You might have better luck with a more specific question that shows you've tried at least something.

Comment: I did try something John... I created an xml file with the same content and wrote it using sqlbulk copy code to write it to the database.... however i manually created that tags... I would like to generate the tags instead...

Comment: The trouble is that you are essentially asking someone to do the whole thing for you. Show the code or whatever you have so far and ask a specific question about the part you are having trouble with. The way it reads right now is "do my work for me". No offense intended, just trying to help you get a useful answer.

Comment: You should also mention the database type you're using, as well as the language you're attempting to do the work in. Adjust your tags accordingly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a list of expected tags?

- If yes, what part is not clear?

  - Just extract all relevant strings from XML (using any parser, you haven't mentioned language so can't give examples).
  - apply regExs that contain the allowed tag and if a match then add the tag.
  - PS: If you have too many tags and/or too much data to deal with applying one regEx/tag to each input string may not be most performant.
- if no, then I suppose you're expected to assume some words are tags and add them. Though I don't like the idea (usually I would expect the user to think and give me tags he wants to mark his inputs with) one way I can think of is to make a list of words you do NOT want to used as tags (e.g. "and", "or", "I", "we", ...), remove all these words using regEx replace, take remaining word